# C++ erroring creating n pthreads-

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, pthreads

Getting the following errors in a function that should take an int k and create k pthreads:

cse451.cpp:95:60: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘pthread_t* {aka long unsigned int*}’ [-fpermissive]

cse451.cpp:97:54: error: invalid use of void expression

I have a feeling it has to do with the foo() function (which at this point is used as nothing more than a placeholder foo(){}  )

The relevant code is listed below (line 95 is pthread_t *threads...... and line 97 is err=pthread_create....)

```
void createThreads(int k){
int numThreads = k;
int i = 0;
int err = 0;
pthread_t *threads = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * numThreads);
for(i = 0;i<numThreads;i++){
    err = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, foo(), NULL);
    if(err != 0){
        printf("error creating thread\n");
    }
}
}

void foo(){}
```

Comment: Please don't edit the question to fix the code. The answers won't make sense if you do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first problem is that you're trying to compile C with a C++ compiler. This conversion:

```
pthread_t *threads = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * numThreads);
```

from an untyped `void*` pointer returned by `malloc`, to a typed `pthread_t*` pointer, is allowed in C but needs a cast in C++.

```
pthread_t *threads = static_cast<pthread_t*>(malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * numThreads));
```

But if this is meant to be C++, you'd be better off with

```
std::vector<pthread_t> threads(numThreads);
```

so you don't need to juggle the memory yourself. You might also want to look at the standard thread library, which is more friendly than POSIX threads.

The second problem is the argument to `pthread_create` should be a function pointer `foo`, not the result of calling a function `foo()`. You also have the wrong type for the function; it must take and return `void*`

```
void *foo(void*);
```

It's passed the argument you provided to `pthread_create` (`NULL` in this case), and returns a pointer to anything you want to receive when you join the thread (`return NULL;` if you don't want to return anything).

Comment: thank you. that took care of one error. still receiving the line 97 invalid use of void expression error

Comment: @jeremy: Sorry, I didn't spot that. A function pointer looks like `foo` not `foo()`.

Comment: seems to not have solved the issue. now receiving:         cse451.cpp:97:52: error: invalid conversion from ‘void (*)()’ to ‘void* (*)
In file included from cse451.cpp:2:0:
/usr/include/pthread.h:244:12: error:   initializing argument 3 of ‘int pthread_                                                                                                                     create(pthread_t*, const pthread_attr_t*, void* (*)(void*), void*)’ [-fpermissiv                                                                                                               e]

Comment: @jeremy: Yes, the function is the wrong type. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Appreciate your attention btw. I have updated the code with ours suggestions but still receiving the errors posted with the updated code

Comment: @jeremy: It looks like the declaration of `foo` (somewhere before the code you've posted) looks like `void *foo();` rather than `void *foo(void*);`

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two things wrong:

- You need to pass a pointer to a function for the third argument to pthread_create, not the result of a call to the function you intend to run in the thread.
- The prototype for the function should be something like

  void *f(void *);

  I.e. it should take a pointer to void as an argument, and return a pointer to void.

Your call to pthread_create should look something like this:

```
void *foo(void*);
err = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, foo, NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> cse451.cpp:97:54: error: invalid use of void expression
> ```

You need to pass the function pointer of `foo()` to `pthread_create()`, instead of calling the function

```
 pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, foo, NULL); // << See the parenthesis are
                                               //    omitted
```